# Is it possible to create a macro / script in iTerm2 that insert text automatically selected from a list?

Tags: python, scripting, applescript, iterm

I use iTerm2 as my default terminal app in OSX. A would like to ask if is possible to insert text automatically with a hotkey (or selecting it from a menu), with iTerm, like the old macros of some word processing packages. My idea is, for example, if I press cmd + ctrl s , iTerm insert automatically "sftp -i"

I know that iTerm has support for scripting with AppleScript and Python  but I'm not sure how I do this

Comment: Okey, I didn't know anything about the snippet functionality. (Prefs>Shortcuts>Snippets)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Keyboard shortcuts.

From Preferences -> Keys
Define a new shortcut and use the "Action" "Send Text"

This works on iTerm2 build  3.4.15

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment on karlacio's Answer but i don't have 50 karma yet.

As of iTerm2 3.4.19, the option is in Preferences > Keys > (+) Add new Key Binding > Under "Send Keystrokes" select "Send Text"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34778570)